# Spam Question from Toronto

Tags: discussion

Incidentally, I‘ve seen quite some spam that looks like the following:

> Irrelevant backstory.
>
> I‘ve seen this treatment **in a clinic in Toronto.** (It‘s always a „clinic in Toronto“)
>
> Has anyone here had a similar situation? What have you done to get rid of the pain? Any advice is highly appreciated. I can't tolerate the pain anymore. Please help!!

I don’t know whether they are explicit spam or OP isn’t affiliated, making it endorsement nonetheless. Is there anything apart from downvotig and flagging we can or should do?

Examples:

- [How helpful is mindfulness based therapy?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12939/8212)
- [Laser eye surgery for flashes in eyes?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12977/8212)

I‘ve reworded this question so that it isn’t spammy or off-topic  anymore (in my opinion)

- [Root canal therapy for diabetes patient?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12132/8212)

Comment: Some of those are apparently still there, having comments and even answers. Still flagging them then? Since one got "excellent" question status: immediate edit removing those spammy parts?

Comment: @LangLangC Updated body with the examples, and I flagged and downvoted all of them. They are suspicious because they link to the doctor and want a recommendation whether the treatment there works. All other posts don’t have links

Comment: What is the policy for spam accounts that are just sitting there, doing nothing but display their "autobiography"?

Comment: @LangLangC Flag any post of the user and add a flag reason. [If that’s not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128618/353950) let me know and I’ll check whether the user has any deleted posts I can still see and flag, or we’ll mobilise the gang. (A few people from Meta StackExchange have socket accounts to downvote, flag etc. users into oblivion. This especially helps during vandalism because sometimes mods aren’t fast enough to contain damage to the site)

Comment: Well, [ChiroSupply](https://stackexchange.com/users/10925926/discount-chiropractic-supplies) keeps a low profile, doesn't post, nothing. I don't see whether this is against policy or benign disclosure.

Comment: It's against policy. [I've reported it, and someone has blacklisted the user](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6478694#6478694). Don't know how long until the user get's deleted.

Comment: @LangLangC Yeah, but it’s not exactly spam. People are allowed to advertise themselves and post rubbish in the user profiles, but they aren’t allowed spam profiles. // I’ve also seen crowds of 600,000 people gather, by the way. Not for me, no, but I doubt he has seen such a tremendous amount of people gather solely for him.

Comment: Not exactly. [This](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/1877/centralpasutri-com) seems like a much better fit. I wonder what the use of this kind of promo is?

Comment: @LangLangC Don’t Ask me. Both Nuked, btw.

Comment: Another one found here [primerxmart](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/9813/primerxmart-valtrex-online). Is there no a better way to uncover those silent profiles?

Comment: @LangLangC Reported it. [This query apparently works](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/677656/likely-spammers-no-rep-link-in-aboutme)

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/health/query/677656/likely-spammers-no-rep-link-in-aboutme // ~170 Results.

Comment: Thx. Just checking… First random find seems benign. Until clicked. Not looking good so far. Only one false positive?

Comment: They've branched out to Oakville now: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/are-dental-implants-possible-in-oakville-any-suggestions

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with these questions.

But an addition needs to be made to the question

> (It‘s always a „clinic in Toronto“)

This astro-turfing SPAM is adaptable to other dentists, clinics etc in $town.

While they might be somehow "fitted" by the spammer into the format of this site, they are still posted by a spammer. These posts may then be *edited by us* to comply to site guidelines, that is: remove the spam part and keep what looks like a genuine question – so they might get an answer – and deserve an answer; on first sight.

**But**

A spammer does not post a serious question, a spammer will not come back with the same login/credentials/name. That means that even if answered, the answer will not get accepted by the OP.

That is unattractive to answer.
That distorts the question…answers:accepted answer ratios for the whole site.

Plus, these are always off-topic for the remainder being still a request for personal medical advice on an opinion-poll basis.

They are a waste of space and time and effort.

**These questions should be destroyed on first sight.**